# tesseract outputs text, but only nonsense

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract on the mac with swedish trained data, http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=swe.traineddata.gz

I run the following from the command line:
sudo tesseract -l swe my.png my.txt

[image: The content of my.png]

and this is what it outputs in my.txt:

```
uavum-rn om: mgm.
:mm om names N............
m fw.
<>..,...,.....1,». mm. ^V.m..»...1 W u
|............................ mmm
m«.......
n....... ~.«......«y.= mm
Am...
M-Q-..y...@»~.U.M........»...........   
.;.§............. MYM... WU..
M. www
.<W..L.....w.m.,w»
mm... Hm... ^......... a.....ß..... M
M..
Hm... 3....
>«........
N
1
G
n.......
mmm
mmm »
mmm
MW:-u >«..«.......
M.».....«@>-ms... .a »mm »1
mm... nu .<....-...WMA _..
m........m mm
WW» m
mm w
.-...............u. 
|-...M-11.”.
|........m :>...1.1-1»-.N
Kwwm
M...-«
|.~.»...:-u1.«..... ,-...........
mm M
.-M».....m ...A m...m..<....ß.-.W
.mwwm .M M»-..U..........k
.....-W... .W-;-1
```

Is there some parameter I miss, one I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I played with this engine but your note rings a bell with me so I checked the site.  I think you need to use this file [Swedish language data for Tesseract 3.02](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.swe.tar.gz&can=2&q=) because I suspect you're using the training data from the previous release.

If I got the root of your problem, mark my answer will you? ;)

Comment: hmm, well replacing the swe.traineddata started giving the following:   actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <=   TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 48  - the swe.traineddata I was using before was http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=swe.traineddata.gz which says it is Swedish language data for Tesseract (3.00 and up)

Comment: Oh - you are not using 3.02?I thought I should look at your image and I think I can

Comment: oops - there was more I wanted to say! I pulled your image and I think I can see the problem: the text is very small and even our OCR engine had a hard time reading the characters. I do not have the time to check but are you sure the image was stored correctly? Can you somehow use an image that is 100% scale of the original?

Comment: Hi, you're probably right. It's converted from a pdf, and I guess there has to be some param to give imagemagick to maintain image size when converting. I'll run it and see if that gives a better result. I installed using brew and it gave me 3.01, since this is exploratory trying to see how tesseract handles some problem documents we have I wanted to just try to get a quick feel for it.

Comment: Actually I am trying to prepare a trained-data of hand written texts and for the first step, I Scanned all the handwritten texts and did sampling and then did all the steps mentioned at code.google.com 's documentation and at then end while using the tessdata (trained-data) in my project with Ver 3.x I had the same problem : actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 48 - your help will be much appreciated